# Android SDK and Facebook SDK - Failed to find build revision 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

I am currently trying to make Facebook SDK cooperate with my Android Studio. I've been following their step-by-step guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started (so far so good), but I am currently hitting a wall. 
While trying to sync my project, I get following error: Failed to find Build Tools 4.0.1.
At this point I did the obvious, clicked the "Install Build" link, which gave the me installer window. I accept the agreement, but when I get to the installing components tab, I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJw7V.png

I've trying messing around with some numbers to see if it was a version error, but no luck.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.notresponding.fbtest"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    }
```

Seeking a solution, thank you :)

EDIT: Adding build.gradle

Comment: Still a big issue with this :/

Comment: if you didn't solve it and you want, and it is not life necessary for you to use exactly 4.0.1 version. I saw many many bags with 4.0.1 coming out during these days. and 4.0.0 works very good. for me at least.

Comment: @Yurets How do I change it to 4.0.0? I tried changing the facebook line to 4.0.0 but it didn't change the error outcome

Comment: Can you upgrade the BuildToolsVersion to use "22.0.1"? (the current most recent).